# What are some FSA eligible expenses that can be used for baby care?

Tags: united-states, savings, health-insurance, eligible-expenses

I signed up for a Flexible Spending Account (FSA), and am now trying to figure out what all is covered under it.

I know some of the basic products like band aids and glasses are, but I'm really curious what baby products I can use my FSA for. Are breast pumps and diapers eligible? Any services I should know about for both during and after pregnancy (can I see a gynecologist?)?

Answer (score 3):

You can find a general list of many common types of expenses and whether they are covered by an FSA [here](http://www.aetna.com/members/fsa/eligibleExpenses/healthcareFSA/healthexpenses_A.html). Please note that this is general information that can be changed at any time, and may not be up to date with current IRS information. Ideally, you could call your employer or insurance company and they could provide you with the most up to date materials.

In the list from Aetna I've linked to, gynecologist and breast pump expenses are included, but infant diaper expenses are not included (they are not considered a qualified medical expense).

You may also want to browse this list to look at other types of eligible expenses you may have.

Some additional related expenses you may have that this list shows as eligible include:

1. Some creams, ointments, and analgesics (if prescribed)
2. Cord blood banking (if medically necessary)
3. Some portions of Lamaze or childbirth classes (if after you signed up)
4. Co-insurance for doctor or hospital fees
5. Counseling or other medical services (counseling for Post-Partum, for example)
6. Educational classes (if medically necessary)
7. Immunizations
8. Lactation Consultant
9. Meals/Lodging while receiving medical care in a hospital or similar facility
10. Massage therapy when medically necessary (not for the baby, but sounds great!)
11. Maternity/Delivery/Obstetrics costs
12. Nutritional supplements, when medically necessary (our doctor recommended Poly-vi-sol, for example)
13. Preventative care (well-baby visits, routine screenings/tests, etc.)
14. Thermometer
15. Teething pain relievers, when prescribed (Orajel, etc.)
16. Ultrasounds
17. Vaporizor/humidifier

In most cases, you will need a receipt, as well as your doctor's written prescription, which they will usually be willing to provide if they are recommending a given product/service.

Again, this list may not be up to date. Please verify the details of any expenses for which you wish to be reimbursed with your employer or health insurer.

Please be aware that if you have a Limited FSA, you may only be eligible for reimbursement of certain types of expenses until after you've met your deductible(s).

Please also be aware that as of 2011, any over-the-counter medication is not FSA-eligible unless you have a doctor's prescription. However, many doctors will write prescriptions for these types of medicines if medically necessary.

Additionally, if you have day care or child care expenses related to time you are away while at work, you may benefit from a Dependent Care FSA (does not cover typical babysitting).

I hope that helps - best of luck and congratulations on the new baby!

Comment: Jag - isn't nanny on DCA (or dependent care FSA, as you reference) not medical FSA?

Comment: http://www.irs.gov/publications/p502/ar02.html is another good source.  Although Aetna made a nicer page to look at.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Yes, I should have specified that. Edited my answer to reflect the distinction. OP did not actually specify a medical FSA only but that is a reasonable assumption in context.

Comment: Good work, Jag, an important distinction, as the accounts are quite different.